# Value assigned is not used in any execution path - C#

Tags: c#, oop, instantiation

Resharper is showing this warning: "value assigned is not used in any execution path" when I write the following code:

```
List<obj> testObj = new List<obj>();
testObj = testMethod();
```

Here `testMethod()` returns type `List<obj>`. However when I directly assign the `testMethod()` without instantiating it, I don't get the warning.

```
List<obj> testObj = testMethod();
```

Forgive me for my ignorance, if I am missing the basics but I'm not following how the compiler allocates memory for `testObj` without instantiating it.

One of the posts refers to similar question: [C# Is this initialiser really redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026646/c-sharp-is-this-initialiser-really-redundant) but I don't find any answer to my question, as to where the `testObj` variable is storing the value it received from `testMethod`? Unlike primitive data types, 'object types' can store value only after they are instantiated. Please let me know, if I am missing something.

Comment: This is indeed duplicate of question you've linked - there is no difference what type of object you instantiate (and there is no reason to create one question per possible type you can `new` instance of  and than immediately ignore that value).

Comment: For reference types the compiler only allocates a pointer, but not the object itself. It's only when you `new` the object does the memory get allocated.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have edited my question and added more details to my question and hope it now differentiates itself and not be a duplicate anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating an instance of a `List<object>` in the first line. And then you throw this object away by assigning the `testObj` variable another value returned from your method `testMethod`. This `new List<obj>()` object is redundant. You effectively creating garbage that Garbage Collector will have to clean at some point.

That's why ReSharper showing you warning.

If you can initialize variable with **actual** value right in the same line where the variable is defined then do it.

EDIT (assuming we are talking about situation provided in the question):

1. `new` operator does not deal with variable itself. It creates a new object in the *heap* (for reference types).
2. `=` operator assigns a **value** to a variable in the *stack*. In this case **value** is a reference to an object in the heap.
3. There is no difference between assigning a value to a variable returned from a method or an object constructor. Object constructor is actually a method too.
4. Variable don't need to be initialized before it's possible to assign a value to it. Actually initialization by definition is an assignment of initial value to a variable.

Comment: I have added more details to my question now to point to my question precisely.
`testMethod` is reading a list of objects from the database and returning it to `testObj` variable. So, isn't `testObj` variable required to be allocated memory before it can be assigned the return value? This is why I `new` it but ReSharper shows a warning that it wasnt required. Hope I am clearer now in what I am asking.

Comment: See updates to the unswer. I put it there for better formatting.

Comment: `int v = new Int32();` does not create anything on the heap :)

Comment: This pretty much answers my question - _There is no difference between assigning a value to a variable returned from a method or an object constructor_ 

Just to summarize my understanding, in my code, value returned by `testMethod` is already residing in the heap and therefore there is no need to create a `new` for my variable `testObj` to hold the value. Unless, `testObj` was assigned values for the first time externally.
Thanks for your explanation :)